# Python - Grouping by multiple columns and getting max or sum

Tags: python, group-by

I am interested in getting max value of the Product price.

Here is the input data.[Download Sales Data](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwiv39SmisjHAhXEpYgKHYmzDyg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fskdatapoller%2Fdownloads%2Fdetail%3Fname%3DSalesData.csv&ei=s2PeVe-5LMTLogSJ577AAg&usg=AFQjCNEV-AT8S5evS3RYIzMc-fgGIuNYZw&sig2=ctxAr7lny06gNMK9CF1fHg)

I want to group by State,Country

How do I go about grouping these two columns get the max value of Price.

```
import csv
import locale
from itertools import groupby

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 

total_price = 0
max_price = 0
reader = csv.DictReader(open('/Users/myuser/Downloads/SalesData.csv', 'rU'), dialect='excel')

groups = groupby(reader, lambda d: d['State'])

result = [max(g, key=lambda d: d['State']) for k, g in groups]

for row in reader:
    print row["State"], row["Country"], locale.atoi(row["Price"])
    max_price = max(row.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    total_price += locale.atoi(row["Price"])
```

With use of panda's. Can I get this without using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import locale

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 


df = pd.read_csv('/Users/myuser/Downloads/SalesData.csv', index_col=False, header=0,thousands=',')

print df.groupby(["Country","State"]).max()["Price"]
```

Comment: What problem are you facing using your code? Provide some sample input and output. Clarify your question a bit please.

Comment: Sure. My intended output is to display max price of the product by country and state.

Comment: @paddu is your csv already sorted according to country/state?

Comment: To use `itertools.groupby` you need to sort your data first.

Comment: @AnandSKumar  - Sorry, it needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` only works on lists sorted using the same key function used for groupby , as given in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) -

> **itertools.groupby(iterable[, key])**
>
> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged. **Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.**

So for achieving what you want with `itertools.groupby` , you would most probably need to sort the data first based on both `'Country'` and `'State'`  , and then take groupby on it.

also, when taking `max()` you should use `'Price'` not `'State'` . Example -

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('/Users/myuser/Downloads/SalesData.csv', 'rU'), dialect='excel')

sortedreader = sorted(reader, key=lambda d: (d['Country'], d['State']))

groups = groupby(sortedreader, key=lambda d: (d['Country'], d['State']))

result = [(k, max(g, key=lambda d: d['Price'])) for k, g in groups]
```

I added the key to the result , to identify which `Country`/`State` each max corresponds to. After this you can iterate over `result` and print each if that is what you really want.

Comment: This works great except that result should be result = [((k, max(g, key=lambda d: d['Price'])) for k, g in groups]). It is missing a brace at the end. Thanks

Comment: Also, isn't that groups = groupby(sortedreader, key=lambda d: (d['Country'], d['State']))

Comment: Yea sorry , copy/paste mistake.

Comment: how to print the result?