# Grouping Objects by Attributes and Counting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of `Animal` objects that needs to be grouped together by 2 attributes `species` and `gender`, while the third attribute `amount` needs to be added up.

How will you go about doing this? Any help greatly appreciated!

**Initial list**

```
[
    zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'male', 10))
    zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'male', 20))
    zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'female', 50))
    zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'female', 10))
    zoo.append(Animal('eagle', 'male', 1))
    zoo.append(Animal('eagle', 'male', 3))
]
```

**Expected list:**

```
[
    Animal('lion', 'male', 30),
    Animal('lion', 'female', 60),
    Animal('eagle', 'male', 4)
]
```

**Failed attempt:**

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, species, gender, amount):

        self.species = species
        self.gender = gender
        self.amount = amount

# need help with this function 
def simplify(zoo):
    simplifiedZoo = []
    for animal in zoo:
        key = animal.species
        d[key].append(...)

    return simplifiedZoo

# Create initial list
zoo = []
zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'male', 10))
zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'male', 20))
zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'female', 50))
zoo.append(Animal('lion', 'female', 10))
zoo.append(Animal('eagle', 'male', 1))
zoo.append(Animal('eagle', 'male', 3))

# Simplify list
simplify(zoo)
```

Comment: constructor of Animal needs species, gender, amount

Comment: Have you considered using `itertools.groupby`?  Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239161/206403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to avoid bumpy key-exists checks while summing. Use `tuples` of `species` **and** `gender` as key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def simplify(zoo):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for animal in zoo:
        d[(animal.species, animal.gender)] += animal.amount
    return [Animal(s, g, a) for (s, g), a in d.items()]
    # Py3: return [Animal(*k, v) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

whithout any library

```
def simplify(zoo):
    simplifiedZoo = {}
    for animal in zoo:
        try:
          simplifiedZoo[(animal.species, animal.gender)].amount += animal.amount 
        except KeyError:
            simplifiedZoo[(animal.species, animal.gender)] = animal
    return [x for x in simplifiedZoo.values()]
```

Comment: You certainly mean `+=` in the `try` block. You should also mention  that this alters the animals in the original zoo.

Comment: @schwobaseggl About 2nd mention - I'm not sure that OP don't want such result. It may be statistics